# ¿ Cómo obtener el valor de un parámetro OUT en un procedimiento almacenado con PDO - PHP y MySQL?

Tags: php7, pdo, stored-procedure

Me intriga saber porque no me funciona el retorno de valores de un `SP` usando `PDO` para conectarme a una base de datos MySql, he leído en la documentación de PHP sobre PDO y he replicado uno de los ejemplos y nada más no me funciona. Mi versión de PHP 7.4.1

Mi procedimiento almacenado de prueba es el siguiente:

```
DELIMITER #
CREATE PROCEDURE tomar(OUT cadena VARCHAR(20))
BEGIN
    SET cadena = 'Hola Mundo';
END #
```

Ahora mi código en `PHP` es el siguiente:

```
 $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=shopic','root','');
                $statement = $connection->prepare('CALL tomar(?);');
                $statement->bindParam(1,$cadena,PDO::PARAM_STR,4000);
                $statement->execute();
                print "Devuelve: $cadena";
```

Estoy usando XAMPP pero también he comprado un hosting para pruebas, en ninguno me ha funcionado, no devuelve nada. Aclarar también que los procedimientos que solo tienen declarados parámetros de entrada me funcionan perfectamente. Mi duda es han cambiado algo, ¿Alguna cosa nueva ha sucedido o qué?

He probado usando un procedimiento que tenga un parámetro `IN OUT` y colocando en el método `bindParam PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::_PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT` y tampoco ha funcionado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Efecto el la [*documentación* (Ejm.4)](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepared-statements.php) aparece tal cuál, pero para `MySQL` en `PDO` no funciona así. Deberá seleccionar desde `PHP` la variable que retorna el procedimiento haciendo un `select` después de ejecutar el procedimiento.

```
//creamos la sentencia con la variable @parametroSalida
 $statement = $connection->prepare('CALL tomar(@parametroSalida)');
 $statement->execute();
 //Obtenemos la variable en formato Array, La primera posición tendrá el valor
 $var = $connection->query("SELECT @parametroSalida")->fetch();
 echo "Devuelve: " . $var[0];
```

O también podemos utilizar [*fetchColumn*()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

```
$var = $connection->query("SELECT @parametroSalida")->fetchColumn();
echo $var;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me tenia muy pensativo ese inconveniente, me ha funcionado todo perfectamente.